# Is there a pseudo class selector for the first of 2 elements?

Tags: css, pseudo-class

I know the plus sign `+` selects the second of 2 elements that are next but not in one another.  Is there a selector for the first element?

I have 2 headings right after one another.  `h3` then `h4`.  I want to remove the bottom margin from the `h3` if an `h4` follows.  Is something like that possible or do I need to just provide a negative top margin to the `h4`?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-css-selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting CSS tricks:

> Let's be clear here, just in case someone is finding this from a
>   search engine: **there are no parent selectors in CSS**, not even in CSS3.

https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/
This article lays out a proposal for a possible parent selector, but due to various performance reasons, browsers would find it difficult to implement

So, the best you can do is negative margins. That's actually a fairly decent solution

```
h3 + h4 {
 margin-top: -10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to style on siblings to come.

You can use a negative margin on the `h4` after an `h3`